# Angular Material drag drop CDK - drop single element(independent) into a list

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to move an independent cdkDrag into a cdkDragList container?

extra question: Is it possible to free move cdkDrag(s) inside a cdkDragList container?

basically what I'm trying to do is to have one list(group) that the items inside can be freely moved, but when entering the second list the items will be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a list of one item.

You want [Transferring Items Between Lists](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#transferring-items-between-lists).